# Distributing MySQL database on n systems

Tags: mysql, architecture, mysql-cluster

I have a webserver in my application which talks to a single MySQL node.  Instead of having just one MySQL node, I want to have a cluster of n nodes which form my database.

Is it possible to do this?  Can some one point to a resource where I can read about how to do this.

I read about MySQL cluster but am more confused now; is there any beginner tutorial for that?

I don't want to rewrite the application, as I am under the impression that application code should never know whether it's talking to one DB node or a cluster of DB Nodes.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2011/php-and-mysql-cluster-load-balancing-without-rw-split/

Comment: sorry but i haven't got a bit of it. My problem is i have a database and a table in it. Now this table is too huge, i just wnat to split it up and keep in say 4 different systems(nodes or computers). but when this database is accessed from my application it should work as though it is in one system. I hope i am clear.

Comment: So you want different records of a table on different servers? How are you expecting to code the searching of records?

Comment: yes it is what i am expecting.i don't think the application code should change anyway, the DB has to have some way to doing this.The application should just work as it was communicating to a single node.

Answer (score 2):

This technique is called Sharding.

MySQL doesn't support this kind of partitioning therefore is necessary to implement sharding logic manually.

I think [Spock Proxy](http://spockproxy.sourceforge.net/), for example, it's a good starting point to think in this direction

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Clustrix, ScaleDB, etc., have solutions for $$$.

But wait...  Do you really need Sharding?  Or do you just need Replication, and have a load balancer in front of a few readonly Slaves?

Slaves solve read-scaling.
Sharding solves write-scaling.

Replication is available out-of-the-box.

Comment: i am not in need of replication but i want both read and writes scaling.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2015 FROM MY PREVIOUS POST 2012 :)**

You can take a look into [MySQL Fabric](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/fabric.html) ([Official Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/fabric.html))

I have tried this tool only in R&D env for testing a basic HA

It supports some [sharding scenarios](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/fabric-quick-start-sharding.html)

Here some high level pros and cons

Pros:

- setup
- sharding
- write/read
- basic HA

Cons:

- fabric node is the SPOF
- no multi master
- rewrite software in order to use the fabric driver